# Problema al volver a ejecutar una función en jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo mi codigo en jQuery el problema es que solo se ejecuta una vez, como puedo reiniciar todos los metodos.

Intente llamarlos de nuevo pero no tiene exito.

```js
                        var paginas = 0;
                        var registrosPage = 10;
                        function determinarPaginas(buscar){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {paginas: paginas, like: buscar},
                                url: 'http://localhost/cecytem/CrudAlumno/getAlumnosForCount',
                                success: function(data){
                                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                    var registros = 0;
                                    
                                    for (var i=0; i<obj['alumnos'].length; i++) {
                                        registros = registros + 1;
                                    }                                    
                                    paginas = registros/registrosPage;
                                    paginas = Math.ceil(paginas);
                                    writePagination(paginas, buscar);
                                },error: function(){
                                    alert("Error contar alumno");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        function obtenerRegistros(page, buscar){                            
                            page = (page - 1) * registrosPage;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {page: page, totalResultados: registrosPage, like: buscar},
                                url: 'http://localhost/cecytem/CrudAlumno/getAlumnos',
                                success: function(data){
                                    writeDatos(data);
                                },error: function(){
                                    alert("Error obtener alumnos");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        function writeDatos(data){                            
                            var datos = JSON.parse(data);
                            var html = '';
                                html += '<div class="table-responsive">';
                                    html += '<table class="table table-striped">';
                                        html += '<thead>';
                                            html += '<tr>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">N° Control</th>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Apellido Paterno</th>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Apellido Materno</th>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Nombre</th>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Curp</th>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Grupo</th>';
                                                html += '<th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</th>';
                                            html += '</tr>';
                                        html += '</thead>';
                                        html += '<tbody>';
                            for (var i=0; i<datos['datosAlumnos'].length; i++) {
                                            html += '<tr>';
                                                html += '<th scope="row">'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].noControl+'</th>';
                                                html += '<td>'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].aPaternoPersona+'</td>';
                                                html += '<td>'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].aMaternoPersona+'</td>';
                                                html += '<td>'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].nombrePersona+'</td>';
                                                html += '<td>'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].curpPersona+'</td>';
                                                html += '<td>'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].noGrupo+'</td>';
                                                html += '<td>';
                                                html += '<a href="<?=base_url()?>CrudAlumno/EditAlumno?curp='+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].curpPersona+'"><span style="color: black;"><i class = "fas fa-user-edit"></i></span></a>';
                                                html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].noControl+'" data-target="#deleteModal" data-whatever="'+datos['datosAlumnos'][i].curpPersona+'"><span style="color: black;"><i class = "fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></button>';
                                                html += '</td>';
                                            html += '</tr>';
                            }
                                        html += '</tbody>';
                                    html += '</table>';
                                html += '</div>';
                                //alert(html);
                                $('#page-content').empty();
                                $('#page-content').append(html);//text('Page ' + page);
                        }
                        function writePagination(paginas, buscar){
                            $('#pagination').empty();                            
                            window.pagObj = $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
                                //Se consulta mediante ajax el total de para las paginas
                                totalPages: paginas,
                                visiblePages: 10,
                                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                                    obtenerRegistros(page, buscar);                                    
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        
                        
                        // Funcion principal
                        $(function () {                            
                            var buscar = '';
                            determinarBusqueda(buscar);
                            
                            var buscarLike = $('[name=searchL]');
                            buscarLike.keyup(function(){
                                detectarTextoBuscar();
                            });
                            
                            function detectarTextoBuscar(){
                                var valor = buscarLike.val();
                                if(valor.length > 0){
                                    determinarBusqueda(valor);
                                }else{
                                    var buscar = '';
                                    determinarBusqueda(buscar);
                                }
                            }
                            
                        });
                        function determinarBusqueda(like){
                            if(like == ''){
                                determinarPaginas(like);
                            }else{
                                determinarPaginas(like);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: no puedo entenderte bien que te parese si intentas explicar mejor que es lo que realmente deseas!

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer un buscador, con AJAX hago las conexiones y funciona.

Comment: Pero solo me funciona una vez, al cargar la pagina me hace la consulta y me muestra los resultados. Y si deseo escribir en mi campo de búsqueda, ya no hace nada.

Comment: Le la misma manera si lo modifico y hago que al cargar no me muestre nada, sino hasta que yo escriba en mi campo busqueda, lo hace pero solo al escribir una letra.

Comment: En la consola no te muestra algún error? `var buscarLike = $('[name=searchL]');` agrega `console.log(buscarLike);` para que confirmes en la consola si cada vez que escribes vas obteniendo los caracteres

Comment: Si va obteniendo datos, lo hice en cada metodo para ver si no se perdia.

Comment: debes tener un evento para que escuche los cabios en el input.Cada vez que pase por el evento,ejecuta las funciones que quieras.